# Create app shortcut to a page in Ionic 1 app

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an IONIC 1 application which have several pages.

I want to create few shortcut on android phone home so we can move direct to that page inside app.

For example a page which url is #app/create_task I want to create a shortcut icon on android phone so clicking on icon directly open this page in app.

A long method I know that create a small app and when its load redirect to app like "myapp://app/create_task". (I know its not a good method)